# Lowest TCP receive window size

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming

What is the lowest possible TCP receive window size can be announced by Linux kernel TCP/IP stack impl and how can i configure to make it announce such one? My goal is to achieve low latency and sacrificing throughput?

Comment: Why do you think that reducing the TCP receive window size reduces latency?

Comment: For low latency you should be using UDP with kernel bypass.

Comment: "For low latency you should be using UDP with kernel bypass" - 

At this moment server accept TCP connections only.

"Why do you think that reducing the TCP receive window size reduces latency?" - 

Right now my test client application reads about 128 bytes each second from buffer and TCP stack waits till there are free SO_RCVBUF/2 bytes space before notifying server about new window size. I'd like to make my client  announce window size lower than SO_RCVBUF/2 if its possible.

Answer (score 1):

> Right now my test client application reads about 128 bytes each second from buffer and TCP stack waits till there are free SO_RCVBUF/2 bytes space before notifying server about new window size. I'd like to make my client announce window size lower than SO_RCVBUF/2 if its possible.

I do not think that changing the receive window size will have any effect on latency.

However, since your messages are small (128 bytes), you may like to disable [Nagle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) **in the sender** that makes the sender wait when sending TCP payload smaller than MSS:

> Applications that expect real-time responses and low latency can react poorly with Nagle's algorithm. Applications such as networked multiplayer video games or the movement of the mouse in a remotely controlled operating system, expect that actions are sent immediately, while the algorithm purposefully delays transmission, increasing bandwidth efficiency at the expense of latency. For this reason applications with low-bandwidth time-sensitive transmissions typically use `TCP_NODELAY` to bypass the Nagle delay.

On the receiver you may like to disable [TCP delayed acknowledgements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_delayed_acknowledgment):

> The additional wait time introduced by the delayed ACK can cause further delays when interacting with certain applications and configurations. If Nagle's algorithm is being used by the sending party, data will be queued by the sender until an ACK is received. If the sender does not send enough data to fill the maximum segment size (for example, if it performs two small writes followed by a blocking read) then the transfer will pause up to the ACK delay timeout. Linux 2.4.4+ supports a `TCP_QUICKACK` socket option that disables delayed ACK.

C++ code:

```
void disableTcpNagle(int sock) {
    int value = 1;
    if(::setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &value, sizeof value)) 
        throw std::system_error(errno, std::system_category(), "setsockopt(TCP_NODELAY)");
}

void enableTcpQuickAck(int sock) {
    int value = 1;
    if(::setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_QUICKACK, &value, sizeof value)) 
        throw std::system_error(errno, std::system_category(), "setsockopt(TCP_QUICKACK)");
}
```

Comment: I agree with your commentary, but the problem is that i dont have access to server and i'd like to know whether its even possible technically to enforce kernel announce lower TCP window on client side.

Comment: @hwasin Added `TCP_QUICKACK` note for you.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this option and still receiver windows size is not reduced. Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55227287/how-to-enable-tcp-quickack-option)

Comment: @hwasin `TCP_QUICKACK` has nothing to do with the receivers window size. The receive window size is controlled by `SO_RCVBUF` socket option.

Comment: But if TCP_QUICKACK option is enabled and hence my 128 bytes ACKnowledgment should be delivered to server then client should announce 128 byte receiver window too, but kernel does not do that, it waits till SO_RCVBUF/2 window size can be announced.

Comment: @hwasin You need to disable Nagle algo in the server. If you are on Linux, you can preload a library into the server that does it without modifying server's code.

Comment: as i said i have no access to server. I need to disable DelayedACK on client side because DelayedACK leads to ACK accumulation and i need to send ACK immediately for 128 bytes read by application.

Comment: @hwasin You need to raise this issue with the developers of the sending application. Changing the receive window size won't help you here.

Comment: Excuse me, but for what? The TCP sender cannot affect TCP client receiver window size. Its receiver's choice what size to announce. Right now i need to know how to announce < SO_RCVBUF/2.

Comment: @hwasin You lost me. Read what I wrote.

Comment: I agree with you that disabling Nagle algorithm would lower latency. Now lets suppose that it is disabled on server. And after that assumption my goal is to ACKnowledge by 1 byte and announce 1 byte window.